# position changing in ios5 with iphone4 and iphone 4s

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have created the game in unity3d IOS. GUI buttons are changed their position s in iphone4 with IOS 5.But it is work well in IOS lower versions.what is the problem,i can't understand this problem.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be cause because of retinal display, The difference between 4,4s and 3gs,3 and older, is the screen resolution, the points are the same, so

your positions shall be like this

```
float scale = ScreenSizeInPixels.width/ScreenSizeInPoints.width;
float x *= scale;
float y *= scale;
```

this should give you new positions

EDIT : in older iphone 3gs and older, scale value should equal to 1.0, so positions will stay the same ( Points = Pixels ), in iPhone 4 and 4s, the value will be around 2.0, that should give you new x and y

Comment: thanks for reply

I am using JavaScript for unity3d . how can i rectify this problem in unity side.

Comment: Hi again, sorry, am not expert in java script, but you have it here the mathmatical equation, search in google on how to get the screensizeinpoints and screensizeinpixels, divide the the pixels width / points width or pixels height / pixels height, then multiply your x and y positions with that scale value